# nested tryCatch not catching error?

Tags: r, try-catch, raise

I have a function:

```
buggy <- function(...) {
    tryCatch({
        itWorked <- FALSE
        stop("I don't like green eggs and ham!")
        itWorked <- TRUE
    }, finally = {
        if ( itWorked )
            return("I do, Sam I am")
        else
            return("I do not like them, Sam I am!")
    })
}
```

Basically, `buggy` tries to do some calculations that may or may not succeed (determined by `itWorked`. The `finally` clause just makes sure that even if the calculation didn't work, something gets returned (in this case, `"I do not like them, Sam I am!"`).

It works as expected:

```
> buggy()
Error in tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers) : 
  I don't like green eggs and ham!
[1] "I do not like them, Sam I am!"
```

Now I want to listen for errors in `buggy()`:

```
tryCatch( buggy(), 
          error=function(e) message('too bad! there was an error') )
```

However the error in `buggy` fails to raise an error in the surrounding `tryCatch`:

```
> tryCatch( buggy(), 
+           error=function(e) message('too bad! there was an error') )
[1] "I do not like them, Sam I am!"
```

I would expect this to say:

```
'too bad! there was an error'
[1] "I do not like them, Sam I am!"
```

Can anyone tell me why this does not work? Do I somehow need to 'raise' errors from within `buggy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer `tryCatch()` doesn't give you the message stored in its `error` argument for *exactly* the same reason that the following call does not:

```
tryCatch("I do not like them, Sam I am!",
    error=function(e) message('too bad! there was an error') )
# [1] "I do not like them, Sam I am!"
```

The message in the `error` argument two lines up would only be invoked if `buggy()` returned an error. But instead (thanks to the work of the `tryCatch()` inside of it), `buggy()` just returns a character vector, and `tryCatch()` has nothing to 'catch':

```
value <- buggy()
value
# [1] "I do not like them, Sam I am!"

# And, to belabor the point:
identical(buggy(), "I do not like them, Sam I am!")  
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Ohh, I see. What then is the standard procedure for `buggy` to return a value on error (intermediate step of the calculation, in my case. I can still use it but want to prevent having to recalculate it), as *well* as flag that an error has occured (and hence the returned result is the intermediate instead of the final one)?

Comment: Forget what I just said, I just realised that in my *particular* case the following will do for my `finally` (I have a parameter `return.intermediate.on.error`): `if ( itWorked || return.intermediate.on.error ) { return(...) } else { stop( reason_for_failure ) }`, and I guess I'll have to store the `reason_for_failure` within the calculation. It doesn't seem the "R way" though. It'd be nice to say: `error = function(e) { raise_error(); return( ... ) }`.

Comment: Would using `warning()` to produce a warning (instead of `stop()` to produce an error) suit your purposes? Since it sounds like you just want to be notified with a message that something has gone wrong, it could be the simplest solution.

Comment: yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks for your explanation too, the behaviour confused me